# Sorting of columns by joining two tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables books and publishers. publisher_id is primary key in publishers table and foreign key in books table. In index.blade.php of books, I want to create link for sorting of columns of book index.
here is my that part of index.blade.php view where I am creating links.

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th><a href="{{ route('books-index',['sort' => 'name','direction' => 'asc']) }}">Name</a></th>
            <th><a href="{{ route('books-index',['sort' => 'published_date','direction' => 'asc']) }}">Published Date</a></th>
            <th><a href="{{ route('books-index',['sort' => 'publisher_name','direction' => 'asc']) }}">Publisher Name</a></th>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Author</th>
```

And in BooksController.php, I have my index method in which sorting part is given below

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $sort = 'created_at';
        $direction = 'desc';
        if(isset($input['sort'])){
            $sort = $input['sort'];
        }
        if(isset($input['direction'])){
            $direction = $input['direction'];
        }

        $books = Book::join('publishers','publishers.id','books.publisher_id')
                ->orderby($sort,$direction)->select('books.*')->paginate(5);
```

Below is given my index view of books
[image: index.blade.php view]

But When I click on publisher_name for sorting, it gives me an error like this.

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 770:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'publisher_name' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `books`.* from `books` inner join `publishers` on `publishers`.`id` = `books`.`publisher_id` order by `publisher_name` asc limit 5 offset 0)
```

So what can I do to solve it?

Comment: can u plz post the publisher migration?

Comment: publisher migration is given below 
"code"
Schema::create('publishers', function (Blueprint $table) { $table->increments('id')->unsigned(); $table->string('name'); $table->string('street'); $table->integer('number'); $table->bigInteger('zip'); $table->string('city'); $table->integer('country_id')->unsigned(); $table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries'); $table->string('license'); $table->timestamps(); }); }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alias `publishers.name` to `publisher_name`, so that mysql can find the alias column:

```php
$books = Book::join('publishers','publishers.id','books.publisher_id')
                ->orderBy($sort,$direction)->selectRaw('books.*, publishers.name AS publisher_name')->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you did in your `join` you have to use dot notation in `$sort` , `table.column` .

Besides that...
This would be the better way to code this:

1. Add a `publisher` relationship to your `Book` Model.

```
function publisher () 
{
    return $this->belongsTo("App\Publisher");
}
```

2. Add a `books` relationship to your `Publisher` Model.

```
function books () 
{
     return $this->hasMany("App\Book");
}
```

3. Change your query to something like this:

```
Book::with("publisher")
           ->orderby($sort, $direction)
           ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: I have done all you wrote above but the same error ocurs

Comment: Books table:
id
name
author_id
published_date
category_id
created_at
updated_at
publisher_id
image

Publisher table:
id
name
street
number
zip
city
country_id
license
created_at
updated_at

Comment: Ok, so there is no column `publisher_name` which means, that this `['sort' => 'publisher_name','direction' => 'asc']` is wrong. It should be `['sort' => 'publisher.name','direction' => 'asc']` (or `publishers.name`).

Comment: If you used your original code it has to be `publishers` . Because I didn't work with joins for a couple of years I don't remember if you have to specify `publishers.name` in the select too.